# Pandas: create a Dataframe from lists with similar-size lists inside

Tags: python, pandas

**I am trying to construct a Dataframe from lists, which have similar-size lists inside.**

In the example below I have 3 lists (with similar-size lists inside), which I want to use to construct an specific Dataframe.

Here are the lists:

```
list_type = [['A1', 'A2'], ['A2'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A4']]

list_xx = [['1', '5'], ['3'], ['2', '7', '3']]

list_date = [['Jan', 'Jan'], ['Feb'], ['Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar']]
```

And the Dataframe I want to construct is:

```py
   date type    xx
0   Jan   A1     1
1   Jan   A2     5
2   Feb   A2     3
3   Mar   A1     2
4   Mar   A3     7
5   Mar   A4     3
```

As you can see, the structure of the Dateframe is based on the inner-lists.

**I would really value an efficient way of doing this in Python.**

Answer (score 2):

You can make do with `concat` and list comprehension:

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({'date':d,'type':t,'xx':xx })
          for d,t,xx in zip(list_date, list_type, list_xx))
```

Or `np.concatenate` with transpose:

```
pd.DataFrame([np.concatenate(l) for l in (list_date,list_type,list_xx)],
             index=['date','type','xx']).T
```

Output:

```
  date type xx
0  Jan   A1  1
1  Jan   A2  5
0  Feb   A2  3
0  Mar   A1  2
1  Mar   A3  7
2  Mar   A4  3
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to flatten the lists first with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, instead of concatenating DataFrames as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60249198/10682164) answer.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

list_type = [['A1', 'A2'], ['A2'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A4']]
list_xx = [['1', '5'], ['3'], ['2', '7', '3']]
list_date = [['Jan', 'Jan'], ['Feb'], ['Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar']]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_date),
    "type": itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_type),
    "xx": itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_xx)
})
```

This gives your desired output. I would expect this to be more efficient than building and concatenating sub DataFrames, but haven't explicitly tested the two.

Comment: Excellent, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you end up going this route.